# xslt to change background color by testing 2 columns

Tags: xml, xslt, colors

I have some xslt code that tranpose the xml file into html. BUt I want to change the cells background color if CallHandled is not equal to CallsRecorded. Here is my xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>AccountName</td>
        <td>AccountKey</td>
        <td>LOB</td>
        <td>LOBKey</td>
        <td>CallHandled</td>
        <td>CallRecorded</td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="FieldingCounts/Row">
        <tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">
              <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </td>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is sample input xml

```
<FieldingCounts>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>[none]</account_name>
    <account_key>-1</account_key>
    <lob_name>[none]</lob_name>
    <lob_key>-1</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>678</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>336</Calls_Recorded>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>ABC</account_name>
    <account_key>342</account_key>
    <lob_name>Grass</lob_name>
    <lob_key>1382</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>1389</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>1226</Calls_Recorded>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>ABC</account_name>
    <account_key>347</account_key>
    <lob_name>Blocks</lob_name>
    <lob_key>1866</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>2544</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>2485</Calls_Recorded>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>HD</account_name>
    <account_key>347</account_key>
    <lob_name>Wood</lob_name>
    <lob_key>2417</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>567</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>567</Calls_Recorded>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>Lowes</account_name>
    <account_key>505</account_key>
    <lob_name>Nails</lob_name>
    <lob_key>2388</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>2622</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>0</Calls_Recorded>
  </Row>
  </Row>
</FieldingCounts>
```

what I want the html to look like

```
<FieldingCounts>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Date</td>
      <td>AccountName</td>
      <td>AccountKey</td>
      <td>LOB</td>
      <td>LOBKey</td>
      <td>CallHandled</td>
      <td>CallRecorded</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013-09-23T00:00:00</td>
      <td>[none]</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>[none]</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>678</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">336</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013-09-23T00:00:00</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>342</td>
      <td>Grass</td>
      <td>1382</td>
      <td>1389</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">1226</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013-09-23T00:00:00</td>
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>347</td>
      <td>Blocks</td>
      <td>1866</td>
      <td>2544</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">2485</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013-09-23T00:00:00</td>
      <td>HD</td>
      <td>347</td>
      <td>Wood</td>
      <td>2417</td>
      <td>567</td>
      <td>567</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2013-09-23T00:00:00</td>
      <td>Lowes</td>
      <td>505</td>
      <td>Nails</td>
      <td>2388</td>
      <td>2622</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">0</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</FieldingCounts>
```

Here is the new OUTPUT html I would like to get

```
<FieldingCounts>
    <tr>
        <td>Date 09-23-2013</td>
    </tr>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="lightgrey" cellspacing="right">
      <td>AccountName</td>
      <td>AccountKey</td>
      <td>LOB</td>
      <td>LOBKey</td>
      <td>CallHandled</td>
      <td>CallRecorded</td>
      <td>CallMissing</td>
      <td>Percentage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="lightyellow">
      <td>[none]</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>[none]</td>
      <td>-1</td>
      <td>678</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">336</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">342</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">49.55%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="lightyellow">
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>342</td>
      <td>Grass</td>
      <td>1382</td>
      <td>1389</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">1226</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">163</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">88.26%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="lightyellow">
      <td>ABC</td>
      <td>347</td>
      <td>Blocks</td>
      <td>1866</td>
      <td>2544</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">2485</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">59</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">97.68%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="lightyellow">
      <td>HD</td>
      <td>347</td>
      <td>Wood</td>
      <td>2417</td>
      <td>567</td>
      <td bgcolor="lightGreen">567</td>
      <td bgcolor="lightGreen">0</td>
      <td bgcolor="lightGreen">100%</td>
    </tr>
    <tr  bgcolor="lightyellow">
      <td>Lowes</td>
      <td>505</td>
      <td>Nails</td>
      <td>2388</td>
      <td>2622</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">0</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">2622</td>
      <td bgcolor="RED">0.00%</td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</FieldingCounts>
```

Here is the xml used to get the new output

```
<FieldingCounts>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>[none]</account_name>
    <account_key>-1</account_key>
    <lob_name>[none]</lob_name>
    <lob_key>-1</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>678</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>336</Calls_Recorded>
    <CallMissing>342</CallMissing>
    <Percentage>49.55</Percentage>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>ABC</account_name>
    <account_key>342</account_key>
    <lob_name>Grass</lob_name>
    <lob_key>1382</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>1389</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>1226</Calls_Recorded>
    <CallMissing>163</CallMissing>
    <Percentage>88.26</Percentage>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>ABC</account_name>
    <account_key>347</account_key>
    <lob_name>Blocks</lob_name>
    <lob_key>1866</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>2544</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>2485</Calls_Recorded>
    <CallMissing>59</CallMissing>
    <Percentage>97.28</Percentage>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>HD</account_name>
    <account_key>347</account_key>
    <lob_name>Wood</lob_name>
    <lob_key>2417</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>567</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>567</Calls_Recorded>
    <CallMissing>0</CallMissing>
    <Percentage>100</Percentage>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <day_date>2013-09-23T00:00:00</day_date>
    <account_name>Lowes</account_name>
    <account_key>505</account_key>
    <lob_name>Nails</lob_name>
    <lob_key>2388</lob_key>
    <CallHandled>2622</CallHandled>
    <Calls_Recorded>0</Calls_Recorded>
    <CallMissing>2622</CallMissing>
    <Percentage>0.00</Percentage>
  </Row>
</FieldingCounts>
```

my xslt so far which isn't correct but I'm trying to get there.....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <tr>Date</tr>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="lightgrey" cellspacing="right">
                <td></td>
                <td>AccountName</td>
                <td>AccountKey</td>
                <td>LOB</td>
                <td>LOBKey</td>
                <td>CallHandled</td>
                <td>CallRecorded</td>
                <td>Missing</td>
                <td>Percentage</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="FieldingCounts/Row">
                <tr bgcolor="lightyellow">
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Calls_Recorded' and ../CallHandled != text()">
                                       <xsl:text>F08080</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Calls_Recorded' and ../CallHandled = text()">
                       <xsl:text>LightGreen</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: which cell do you want to change?

Comment: CallRecorded but I also would like to format altenating rows with light grey and darker grey

Comment: my answer includes check for both cells. update the test condition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:for-each xmlns:xsl="sdfa" select="FieldingCounts/Row">
   <tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="./*">
         <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">
            <xsl:if test="(position() = 6 and normalize-space(../*[position()=7]) != normalize-space(.)) or (position() = 7 and normalize-space(../*[position()=6]) != normalize-space(.))">
               <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                  <xsl:text>red</xsl:text>
               </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
         </td>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following XSLT, will change the background color of `Calls_Recorded` cell if it is not equal to `CallHandled`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Date</td>
                <td>AccountName</td>
                <td>AccountKey</td>
                <td>LOB</td>
                <td>LOBKey</td>
                <td>CallHandled</td>
                <td>CallRecorded</td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="FieldingCounts/Row">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="./*">
                        <td>
                            <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="local-name() = 'Calls_Recorded' and ../CallHandled != text()">
                                        <xsl:text>RED</xsl:text>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for the help but this makes the entire table the color that is in the otherwise condition or tag. I got data in the 2 columns that are equal like 10 and 10. I also have rows were the 2 columns are not equal like 25 and 14.

Comment: Well if you don't want a standard color, you can remove the `otherwise`. If you want something totally different, maybe it would help to `edit` your question, provide a input XML and provide a expected output HTML file.

Comment: I have added sample data and html code. Isn't that I want a standard color or not. I just need the cell to be shaded not the entire table. I can live with the entire row to be shaded if that is possible as well.

Comment: I updated my answer to meet your criteria. This XSLT should give the expected output

Comment: markdark thanks for the help it was very helpful. Ihad to add another "when" statement to change color to green when they are equal. Can you help me out one more time? I need to add 2 more columns and change the colors to those and remove the first column date and just add the date to the top of the table. 

in the new column I need "misisng" column to be red when is more then zero and if equal to zero be green. 
in the percentage column I need it red when less then 99, yellow when 99 - 99.99 and green when 100. Also like to have "%" added to it.